# I can't get access to the object global $user from external file in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, global

in the external file i use:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($path."/drupal");
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

global $user;
print $user->name;//it returns nothing
```

This external file i load using AJAX. May be because of it i have these troubles?

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","localhost/drupal/sites/all/themes/MyBartik/templates**team.php***?team_id="+str,true);
```

But this code works:

```
$account = user_load(2);
print $account->name;
```

How can I get the name of the current user in Drupal 7?

when i write:

```
print_r $user;
```

It returns:

```
stdClass Object ( [uid] => 0 [hostname] => ::1 [roles] => Array ( [1] => anonymous user ) [cache] => 0 )
```

instead of:

```
stdClass Object ( [uid] => 1 [name] => admin [pass] => $S$CyyoOFpUD2X.4w8PHsIpWVHinwFZGIG3ZS/uQCz8W/lollB7UwCT [mail] => foo@example.com...
```

Here it is the AJAX function:

```
function showTeam(str){                                     
                                             jQuery("#popup_content").fadeIn("slow");                                             
                                            if (str=="")
                                              {
                                              document.getElementById("jShowTeam").innerHTML="";
                                              return;
                                              }
                                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                                              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                                              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();                                       
                                              }
                                            else
                                              {// code for IE6, IE5
                                              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");                                 
                                              }
                                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                                              {
                                              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                                {
                                                document.getElementById("jShowTeam").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                                                }
                                              }

                                            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/drupal/sites/all/themes/MyBartik/templates/team.php?team_id="+str,true);                           xmlhttp.send();                                     
}
```

Comment: Where is the external file? same domain? Where do you call that AJAX from, same domain? That may help get some answers.

Comment: External php is placed here: `C:\xampplite\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\themes\MyBartik\templates\team.php` I call AJAX from the file which is placed here: `C:\xampplite\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\themes\MyBartik\js\showteam.js`

Comment: I don't have time to check but it may work: If you are writing your own module, always 
call user_load() before calling a function that expects a fully loaded $user object, unless you are sure this has 
already happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had this same problem (with the exact same code). I'm sure OP moved on in the last 2 years, but I'll leave this here for you - yes you, reader.

Open this file:

```
sites/default/settings.php
```

And on about line 328 there is a commmented line like

```
#$cookie_domain = '.example.com';
```

Uncomment it and put your domain in there, don't forget to leave in the prefix dot. You'll have to log in again and it should work.