# Drupal 6 - getting $user->uid = 0 for a logged in user on one particular bespoke module

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-6, global

This one has me really perplexed.

I've got a custom Drupal 6 module which returns a custom page and makes use of the $user object.

The only problem here is, when I  perform the following

```
global $user; print $user->uid ;
```

I'm returned a value of 0 and not 1. It doesn't happen anywhere else in the system. Just in this one place constantly. Please bare in mind nothing else has happened in this module's page function. Not sure if it helps, but here's the menu item.

```
  $items['notplayingnicemodule'] = array (
    'type' => MENU_CALBACK,
    'page callback' => 'adaptive_notplayingnice',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('adaptiveuser'),
  );
```

Has anyone else come across something similar? I wondered if it a memory issue (although nothing in the logs)

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Looks like you might need to provide more info. Are you calling $user directly from the page callback as above, or in a sub-function or theme template? Is other content on the page displaying correctly? You're not getting a 403 (if adaptiveuser perm isn't given to anonymous users)? I assume the MENU_CALBACK spelling error isn't in your original code?

Answer (score 2):

The following answer worked for me , try it

Just had this same problem (with the exact same code). I'm sure OP moved on in the last 2 years, but I'll leave this here for you - yes you, reader.

Open this file:

sites/default/settings.php
And on about line 328 there is a commmented line like

## $cookie_domain = '.example.com';

Uncomment it and put your domain in there, don't forget to leave in the prefix dot. You'll have to log in again and it should work.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790726/i-cant-get-access-to-the-object-global-user-from-external-file-in-drupal-7)